# WordPress on Elastic beanstalk external RDS ,EFS

Tags: wordpress

I am following the below aws link to deploy high available WordPress app on the elastic beanstalk.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/php-hawordpress-tutorial.html

but I am not able to finish it off, where I am getting issues at mounting EFS and having my WordPress code in EFS.

1. In this article using .ebextensions and in that there is efs create, mount scripts so I have update vpc and subnets according to my infra still ending up failing.

please help with what else I am missing on this

getting following errors

2022-06-08 11:41:19 UTC+0530
ERROR
Deleting security group named: awseb-e-umh3prditb-stack-loadbalancersg-3H8HOI31196I failed Reason: vpc-id (Service: AmazonEC2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidParameterValue; Request ID: 3ccc1932-36f8-4170-a914-cc39b3908843; Proxy: null)
2022-06-08 11:41:18 UTC+0530
ERROR
Deleting security group named: awseb-e-umh3prditb-stack-MountTargetSecurityGroup-1X6EEF17U2MYO failed Reason: vpc-id (Service: AmazonEC2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidParameterValue; Request ID: 703da33a-bca6-419c-a148-674b144b2cd5; Proxy: null)
2022-06-08 11:38:22 UTC+0530
WARN
Environment health has transitioned from Ok to Warning. Application update is aborting (running for 35 seconds).
2022-06-08 11:38:15 UTC+0530
ERROR
Deleting security group named: awseb-e-umh3prditb-stack-loadbalancersg-3H8HOI31196I failed Reason: vpc-id (Service: AmazonEC2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidParameterValue; Request ID: 0efaea85-081f-4886-a236-cef18863edf0; Proxy: null)
2022-06-08 11:38:15 UTC+0530
ERROR
Deleting security group named: awseb-e-umh3prditb-stack-MountTargetSecurityGroup-1X6EEF17U2MYO failed Reason: vpc-id (Service: AmazonEC2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidParameterValue; Request ID: dd6d9505-66b1-4610-9593-630e27a40ab3; Proxy: null)
2022-06-08 11:37:43 UTC+0530
ERROR
Failed to deploy application.
2022-06-08 11:37:43 UTC+0530
ERROR
Creating security group named: awseb-e-umh3prditb-stack-MountTargetSecurityGroup-1X6EEF17U2MYO failed Reason: vpc-id (Service: AmazonEC2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidParameterValue; Request ID: e1b20536-9371-4c82-999f-8f75b50e65f2; Proxy: null)
2022-06-08 11:37:43 UTC+0530
ERROR
Creating security group named: awseb-e-umh3prditb-stack-loadbalancersg-3H8HOI31196I failed Reason: vpc-id (Service: AmazonEC2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidParameterValue; Request ID: 71b7f6ba-416e-4139-a1b4-3e9e26ca9c48; Proxy: null)
2022-06-08 11:37:43 UTC+0530
ERROR
Service:AmazonCloudFormation, Message:Stack named 'awseb-e-umh3prditb-stack' aborted operation. Current state: 'UPDATE_ROLLBACK_IN_PROGRESS' Reason: The following resource(s) failed to create: [MountTargetSecurityGroup, FileSystem, loadbalancersg].
2022-06-08 11:37:18 UTC+0530
INFO
Environment update is starting.

Thanks
Srikanth K

Comment: getting following errors

Comment: able to resolve fix this issue by selecting PHP version 7 instead 8